# Mamp for Windows

Tags: mamp

I just installed MAMP for windows. When I try to start servers I get a message "'Apache' needs open port 80 which is already being used by another service or application. Please reconfigure 'Apache' to use free port." I've tried to change in preferences but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you installing MAMP (Mac Apache Mysql Php) instead of WAMP (Windows Apache Mysql Php)? The **M** stands for **Mac**, and if you're running Windows it's not a Mac. Then change it to use a port other than 80.

Comment: I was installing WAMP. Just a typo. Sorry about that. I was able to reconfigure the port though.

Comment: MAMP and MAMP PRO is also available for Windows. It was renamed in "My Apache MySQK PHP" See: http://www.mamp.info/en

Comment: I tried the beta version of MAMP for Windows but ran into some issues. I contacted their customer service and was told that there was still a few bugs they were working out. I ended up using Xampp, which has been working perfectly.